# SQL inner join and on multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

so, I am creating an music database.
I am using three tables (files, categories, categories_assignments).

I want to be able to select a file that is in multiple categories (e.g. a song that is both pop and rock)

I already have made the `or` variance (included below for reference)

```
SELECT DISTINCT `files`.`filename` FROM `files`
INNER JOIN `categories_assignments` 
ON `files`.`id` = `categories_assignments`.`fileid`
INNER JOIN `categories` 
ON `categories_assignments`.`catid` = `categories`.`id`
WHERE `categories`.`name` = 'rock' OR `categories`.`name`='pop';
```

Comment: and the question is?   ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a "set-within-sets" problem -- you are looking for songs that have a set of categories.  I like to solve this using `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT f.filename
FROM files f JOIN
     categories_assignments ca 
     ON f.id = ca.fileid JOIN
     categories c
     ON ca.catid = c.id
WHERE c.name IN ('rock', 'pop')
GROUP BY f.filename
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- I don't see a need to put backticks around every identifier.  That just makes the query harder to read.
- You should use `IN` instead of multiple `OR` comparisons.
- If you are learning SQL, then `SELECT DISTINCT` is almost never useful.  Learn to use `GROUP BY` first.

Answer (score 0):

Group by the file and take only those groups having both categories

```
SELECT f.filename
FROM files f
INNER JOIN categories_assignments ca ON f.id = ca.fileid
INNER JOIN categories c ON ca.catid` = c.id
WHERE c.name in ('rock', 'pop')
GROUP BY f.filename 
HAVING count(c.name) = 2
```